# Add another if condition

Tags: shell

The following script is working fine.

```
for i in `cat /app/scripts/symantec_scripts/list`
do ssh root@$i "uname -n
if [ -s /app/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat ]; then
  cat /app/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
else
  cat /opt/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
fi
echo `service rtvscand status`
echo ....................................................................." ; done | tee /tmp/symantec_info.`date +"%m%d%y"`
```

We have some new servers with the file location in `/usr/symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat`.

How can I add the above line into the script?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: `while read -r i ; do : ... ; done < /app/scripts/symantec_scripts/list` is probably better than for and cat with command substitution.

Answer (score 1):

```
: ...
elif [ -s 'the other file' ]; then
   : ...
fi
```

The syntax is documented in bash(1).

Comment: where do I put the echo `service rtvscand status` in the script?
for i in `cat /app/scripts/symantec_scripts/list`
do ssh root@$i "uname -n
if [ -s /app/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat ]; then
  cat /app/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
else
if [ -s /usr/symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat ]; then
  cat /usr/symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
else
  cat /opt/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
fi
fi
echo ....................................................................." ; done | tee /tmp/symantec_info.`date +"%m%d%y"`

Answer (score 1):

The logical extension to your if test would be to use `elif` (else if)

```
if [ -s /app/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat ]; then 
  cat /app/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat 
elif [ -s /usr/symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat]; then 
  cat /usr/symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
else
 cat /opt/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
fi
```

You might want to refactor as a loop

```
for dir in /app/Symantec /usr/symantec /opt/Symantec
do
  if [ -s $dir/virusdefs/definfo.dat ]
  then
    cat $dir/virusdefs/definfo.dat
  fi
done
```

This is slightly slower but makes it easier to extend to multiple directories

Comment: The following is working :

Comment: for i in `cat /app/scripts/symantec_scripts/list`
do ssh root@$i "uname -n
if [ -s /app/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat ]; then
  cat /app/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
else
if [ -s /usr/symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat ]; then
  cat /usr/symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
else
  cat /opt/Symantec/virusdefs/definfo.dat
fi
fi
echo `service rtvscand status`
echo ....................................................................." ; done | tee /tmp/symantec_info.`date +"%m%d%y"`

Comment: but for some reasons, 
It does not give the result of 
echo `service rtvscand status`
However, on every server I can type it maually,

Comment: # echo `service rtvscand status`
rtvscand is running

Comment: How can I get the 
echo `service rtvscand status`
to work within the script?

Comment: You dont need the echo wrapper, just call `/sbin/service rtvscand status 2>&1` directly.  Also note the full path to service just in case it's not found.